# Getdate in CTE causing excessive multiplication of data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a CTE in my query below that is supposed to calculate the amount sold of a given item for the past 45 days along with showing a 6 week trailing average of that item's sale.

The problem is that the 45 day calc and ship date are causing the whole query to multiply all the data (this query should produce 1 line vs 25 lines for the output). I identified that the shipdate and get date were the lines of code in the CTE causing the multiplication of the query but can't figure out how to correct the problem as it looks like I'm doing everything correctly.

Could use guidance on how to modify the date / get date fields to properly show the data.

I tried commenting out the following lines of code which corrected the issue as the output should be a single line for this query vs several dozen lines.

```
tl.shipdate (in select field)
tl.shipdate (in group by field)
where DATEDIFF(day, tl.shipdate, GETDATE() ) > 45
```

Here's the total query - the lines I commented out above to correct the query are below in the ItemPurchased CTE

```
 With ItemMetrics As
( 
 select ilm.item_id, 
 ilm.REORDER_POINT ReorderPnt,  
 ilm.PREF_STOCK_LEVEL PrefStockLvl,
 ilm.on_hand_count OnHandCnt,
 ilm.on_order_count OnOrderCnt,
 ilm.available_count AvailableCnt
   from ns.ITEM_LOCATION_MAP ilm
     where ilm.location_id = 3
), 

ItemPurchased As 
(
 select sum(tl.unit_qty) TotalItemsBought, sum(tl.unit_qty)/6 
 SixWkAverage, i.item_id,tl.shipdate
   from ns.tinvoice ti
     join ns.transaction_lines tl on ti.transaction_id = 
        tl.transaction_id
     join ns.items i on i.item_id = tl.item_id
 where DATEDIFF(day, tl.shipdate, GETDATE() ) > 45
 group by i.item_id,tl.shipdate
)

select tp.tranid, i.item_id, i.full_name, 
   i.displayname,sum(tl.item_count) -1 AmtOrdered, tl.location_id,  
   it_class.LIST_ITEM_NAME, tp.date_requested Due, v.printoncheckas 
   Vendor, tp.shipment_received ShipmntRecvd, IM.ReorderPnt, 
   IM.PrefStockLvl, IM.OnHandCnt, IM.OnOrderCnt, 
   IM.AvailableCnt,ipp.TotalItemsBought, ipp.SixWkAverage
     from ns.tPurchaseOrder tp
       inner join ns.Transaction_lines tl on tp.transaction_id = 
         tl.transaction_id 
       join ns.items i on i.item_id = tl.item_id
       left join ns.ITEM_CLASSIFICATION it_class on it_class.list_id 
         = i.ITEM_CLASSIFICATION_ID
       left join ns.vendors v on i.vendor_id = v.vendor_id
       left join ns.dw_item_inventory_totals iit on i.item_id = 
           iit.item_id
       left join ItemMetrics IM on im.item_id = i.item_id
       left join ItemPurchased IPP on ipp.item_id = i.item_id
          where tp.date_requested is not null and tp.location_id = 3 
          and tranid = '14980PO'
       group by i.item_id, tp.date_requested, i.displayname, 
         tl.location_id, i.full_name, it_class.LIST_ITEM_NAME, 
         tp.item_id, v.printoncheckas, tp.tranid, 
         tp.shipment_received, IM.ReorderPnt, IM.PrefStockLvl, 
         IM.OnHandCnt, IM.OnOrderCnt, IM.AvailableCnt, 
         ipp.TotalItemsBought, ipp.SixWkAverage
```

Comment: You should illustrate that with the schema as `CREATE TABLE` statements, sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements and the desired result for that sample data.

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't group by `tl.shipdate` in your `ItemPurchased` CTE if you don't plan on using it as a join condition in your final select (`left join ItemPurchased IPP on ipp.item_id = i.item_id`)

Comment: I do have tl.shipdate in my group by statement currently in the ItemPurchased CTE

Comment: I meant "shouldn't". The group by on shipdate is causing the multiplication of rows (because for each item id you're getting one row for each shipdate). But in your final select, you only care about the itemid.

Comment: that worked! I just used max for shipdate - why would that have caused a multiplying effect?

Answer (score 0):

Per the comment from ZLK, using Max(tl.shipdate) and removing shipdate from the group by statement resolved the issue as having shipdate in the group by caused each line to multiply.